# Restoring in-app purchases on iOS 8 without user interaction?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, apple-id

Is it possible to check if a user bought an in-app purchase without having him to login to his Apple ID/AppStore first?

(The reason I'm asking is because I would like to restore previously bought items automatically for returning users)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible without user interaction. And you shouldn't worry about it either. Apple does lay importance to it, but only to the point that you should put the button to restore previous purchases visibly enough.